# Check if my app folder has been accessed

Tags: java, android, storage

Been looking for this problem for about a week now. **How to check if a third party app has requested Read/Write permissions for my app's storage folder?**

What I have in mind is:

```
private String TAG = "concernedClass";
private boolean myAppIsRunning;
//myAppIsRunning is set true when the app is in foreground
if(myAppIsRunning){
    //do something
}else if(!myAppIsRunning && (/*code to check if my app's storage folder was accessed*/)){
    Log.v(TAG,"Folder was accessed");
}
```

What should I replace `/*code to check if my app's storage folder was accessed*/` with?

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to do that, if by "accessed" you mean "looked at". The closest thing that I can think of is `FileObserver`, and that requires that your process be continuously running, which is impractical and typically user-hostile.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've updated the question. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

> How to check if a third party app has requested Read/Write permissions for my app's storage folder?

There is no such concept in Android.

If "my app's storage folder" refers to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), third-party apps cannot have access to it.

If "my app's storage folder" refers to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), third-party apps can have access to it, but they request access to *all* of external storage, not something unique to your app.